# Company Domain assign Heroku IP

Tags: dns, heroku-api

I have a node.js application in Heroku, and I need to use company domain Name.
MIS told me to get the Static IP from Heroku, but I search some documents, there is no way to get Static IP from Heroku.

Is there any way that I can use Heroku service with company domain Name???

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Custom Domain Names for Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) docs, once there follow the [Summary steps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#summary-of-steps) to use the domain.

> You usually configure a new `CNAME` record with your DNS provider to point it at Heroku

For outbound requests, if need fixed IP's check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fixie